# FLATTEN or SUBSTRING messes with JOIN in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two datasets, `data1` and `data2`.

`data2` has following data,

```
a1:u:11#eve:f:6
a1:u:12#eve:f:6
a1:u2:13#eve:f:3
a1:u1:12#eve:s:6
a1:u1:11#eve:f:6
```

Here `:` as well as `#` are delimiters. I generate `data2` finally as,

```
LOAD '$data2' USING PigStorage(':') AS
                 (ad: chararray,
                  a_id: chararray,
                  cid_eve1: chararray,
                  name: chararray,
                  len: int);
```

Then I separate 3rd column into two,

```
FOREACH data2 GENERATE
                  ad AS ad,
                  a_id AS a_id,
                  FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(cid_eve1, '#')) AS (cid: int, eve1: chararray),
                  name AS name,
                  len AS len;
```

Now, when I join `data2` with `data1`, I get nothing.

I have also tried,

```
FOREACH data2 GENERATE
                  ad AS ad,
                  a_id AS a_id,
                  SUBSTRING(cid_eve1,0,INDEXOF(cid_eve1,'#',0)) AS cid: int,
                  name AS name,
                  len AS len;
```

This also returns nothing when joined. I am joining on 3rd column, `cid`.

I have even dumped `data2` for both cases and seen the output. It is what is expected. But when I use following file as `data2`,

```
a1:u:11:eve:f:6
a1:u:12:eve:f:6
a1:u2:13:eve:f:3
a1:u1:12:eve:s:6
a1:u1:11:eve:f:6
```

and load as,

```
LOAD '$data2' USING PigStorage(':') AS
             (ad: chararray,
              a_id: chararray,
              cid: int,
              eve1: chararray,
              name: chararray,
              len: int);
```

Then the join returns correct results. I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone please help or give any suggestions.

`data1`, 2nd col(`$1`) is `a_id` and last col is `cid`. Join is on both of them.

```
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,31,11
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,32,11
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,33,11
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,31,11
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,32,11
1,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,11,21,33,11
2,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,12,22,34,12
2,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,13,22,35,13
2,u1,true,false,4,1,1,1,1,0,12,22,34,12
2,u1,true,false,4,1,1,1,1,0,13,22,35,13
2,u1,true,true,9,1,1,1,1,1,12,22,34,12
2,u1,true,true,9,1,1,1,1,1,13,22,35,13
3,u,false,false,4,1,0,1,0,0,14,24,31,14
3,u,false,false,4,1,0,1,0,0,11,22,31,11
4,u,true,NULL,0,1,1,0,0,0,11,22,33,11
4,u1,false,NULL,0,1,0,0,0,0,11,22,33,11
2,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,12,22,34,12
2,u,true,true,4,1,1,1,1,1,13,22,35,13
2,u2,true,true,7,1,1,1,1,1,12,22,34,12
2,u2,true,true,7,1,1,1,1,1,13,22,35,13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem lies in datatypes. I was trying to read `chararray` into `int` but without typecasting it.

When I changed it to,

```
FOREACH data2 GENERATE
              ad AS ad,
              a_id AS a_id,
              (int)SUBSTRING(cid_eve1,0,INDEXOF(cid_eve1,'#',0)) AS cid,
              name AS name,
              len AS len;
```

It worked.